# execute python code on html button click in Django

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I have a code(function) written in python which I need to execute when a Button on HTML is clicked. I'd prefer not to use a form. Is there any way other than using forms by which I can execute code on HTML Button click.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a *Django* `Form`. Depending on what you want to achieve you can do it in two ways:

1. Still build an *HTML* form that submits to a Django view, but it does not include any validation, so the view just calls your Python code and then redirects to a new page.
2. Implement a Javascript call (AJAX) on the button which will trigger a Django view in the background. This view will not redirect to a new page, but will instead return some JSON which contains resulting data or just a simple value indicating that the action performed correctly.

If you don't want to refresh the whole page, then the second solution will be better.

Comment: Is it necessary to use Ajax or jQuery for second approach? How would I do that?

Comment: If you're not using any other specific Javascript framework then jQuery might be the easiest to add. I don't know a good tutorial off-hand, but I believe there should be many resources out there. How much experience do you have with that?

Comment: Not much. I just began using Django for my project. I need to find resources. Please tell me if you find any. Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/ , https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/ and many more for help

Comment: You can refer to https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html if you want to process something using python on button click using ajax